# Ставится ли запятая перед «как» и «когда»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Красный Солдат как будто лучше знал(?) как и под каким углом делать выстрел.
Красный Пиро как будто лучше знал(?) когда выпрыгивать из-за угла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Красный Солдат как будто лучше знал, **как и под каким углом** делать выстрел.*

*Красный Пиро как будто лучше знал, **когда** выпрыгивать из-за угла.*

Запятая ставится в сложноподчиненном предложении с придаточным изъяснительным перед союзным словом ***когда*** и союзным сочетанием ***как и под каким углом***.

Сравнительный союз ***как будто***   используется в значении **частицы** и относится к глаголу: ***как будто знал***, запятая перед ним не ставится.